# Search specific text on a webpage using xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to search specific text on a webpage using XPath.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.barringtonsports.com/browse/hockey_sticks/show/325/list';
$html = file_get_contents($url);        
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);     
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$found = $xpath->evaluate("//span[contains(text(),'blablabla')]");
if(!$found){
   echo "NOT FOUND";        
}
else{
    echo "found";
}
?>
```

it always give the output found as the text blablabla is not in the webpage.
where is the problem?
Is my evalute expression correct for searching specific text?

Comment: Can you show us a spefic example of a `span` you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: You could use `//span[contains(.,'blablabla')]` if the result change

Comment: I want to search text "Malik Candy FC Composite Hockey Stick" on the webpage.whether it exist or not..

Comment: That doesn't look like a `span`. Could you show us the actual HTML code for the `span`?

Comment: <span class="product_title">Malik Candy FC Composite Hockey Stick</span> that the actual html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

evaluate will not return a boolean for a XPath expression that selects a node, you have to use:

```
$found = $xpath->evaluate("boolean(//span[contains(text(),'blablabla')])");
```

Comment: I would use `exists()` in place of `boolean()`.

Comment: @SiKing there is no `exists()` in XPath 1.0

Comment: Did not know PHP uses only XPath 1.0. Good to know!